# Entity Framework 4: Is it possible to set up Table-per-hierarchy inheritence from scratch?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I've just started playing with EF4, having used NHibernate since about v0.6. I'm trying out the model-first approach. I've got an abstract base class with two subclasses that I want to persist with the TPH strategy, but this doesn't seem to be possible through the designer as there doesn't seem to be a way to set up the storage model and mappings in the way I think it should be. I seem to have the following options:

1. Edit the storage model in the .edmx by hand.
2. Let it generate the schema using TPT, fix that and then update the model and fix up the mappings.

Am I missing something obvious, or should I just revert to db-first and/or hope that the Code-first stuff gets a proper release soon.

Comment: Not out-of-the-box, but possible with third party add-ons: http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/10/mixing-inheritance-strategies-in-entity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no possibility to create a new model with TPH in Model First, you should use one of the workarounds.
As for Code First, take a look at [this article](http://idevign.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/code-first-with-ef4/), it should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks - that's the conclusion I came to. Thanks for the code-first link; I'll give that a play.